# Find duplicate rows and sum the values of a column

Tags: excel, vba

I have 18000 rows and 26 columns.

Sample data:

```
A(Name)     B(Mat_Num)  C(Items) D(group)   E(Summon)   F(Plant) G(Batch_num)
1.Ram       1235         HA1      Micro      545.5      1327      893A1
2.ram       12354        rt2      Senf       5678       0001      1063F
3.Joseph    12354        cf1      Macro      9844       0001      1063F
4.andreas   12354        dw1      HR         6633.95    0001      1063F
5.John      1235         ff1      Finance    22555.09   1327      893A1
6.Russel     987         ad1      Sales      6423       0001      jjg67
7.Holger      00         dd1      purchase   3333       1327      dd567
8.Gottfried   234        fa1      rot        663        345       45678
```

I have to find duplicate rows based on columns (B, F, G). If the rows of these three columns are the same then sum the value of cells of column E to one row and delete duplicate rows to keep only one of the rows.

Result:

```
 A(Name)     B(Mat_Num)  C(Items) D(group)   E(Summon)   F(Plant) G(Batch_num)
1.Ram       1235         HA1      Micro      23101      1327      893A1
2.ram       12354        rt2      Senf       22155.95   0001      1063F
```

I have gone through some websites and blogs to come up with code posted below.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim LastRowcheck As Long, n1 As Long
    Dim DelRange As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        LastRowcheck = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For n1 = 1 To LastRowcheck
            If .Cells(n1, 1).Value = Cells(n1 + 1, 1).Value Then
                If DelRange Is Nothing Then
                    Set DelRange = .Rows(n1)
                Else
                    Set DelRange = Union(DelRange, .Rows(n1))
                End If
            End If
        Next n1

        If Not DelRange Is Nothing Then DelRange.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should quickly take care of it. As quickly as 18K rows of data can be processed to an aggregate sum.

```
Sub Sum_and_Dedupe()
    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        'deal with the block of data radiating out from A1
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            'step off the header and make one column wider
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count + 1).Offset(1, 0)
                .Columns(.Columns.Count).Formula = "=sumifs(e:e, b:b, b2, f:f, f2, g:g, g2)"
                .Columns(5) = .Columns(.Columns.Count).Value
                .Columns(.Columns.Count).Delete
            End With

            'remove duplicates
            .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(2, 6, 7), Header:=xlYes
        End With
        .UsedRange
    End With
End Sub
```

This took ~18 seconds for 18K rows of random data. Your own results will vary according to hardware and software but that should be the ballpark.

[image: sum_and_dedupe_before]
                <sup>Sample data before Sum_and_Dedupe()</sup>

[image: sum_and_dedupe_after]
                <sup>Sample data after Sum_and_Dedupe()</sup>

Comment: @Jeepad got an error at this line as application error or object defined error .Columns(.Columns.Count).Formula = "=sumifs(e:e, b:b, b2, f:f, f2, g:g, g2)"

Comment: I based my sample data on what you provided. I cannot see how you would get an error like that unless you were running xl2003 (which did not have SUMIFS).

Comment: @Jeepad I am running xl2013. I dont know where could we went wrong.

Comment: @jeepad Does your code works if the cells are empty in the sheet? please let me know

Comment: Yes it does work with blanks. Why wouldn't it? What part of the code didn't you think worked with blanks?

Comment: @jeepad is there any other  way to do the same work because its throwing an error .Columns(.Columns.Count).Formula = "=sumifs(e:e, b:b, b2, f:f, f2, g:g, g2)

Comment: No, I really think you should figure out why a standard sumifs formula is causing an error.

Comment: Now its working fine but takes more time to excute and also its not summing up the value in the columns required rather its just deleting the duplicate row. Could you please help me with this.

Comment: its working absolutely fine but i would like to add another column to be summed up. when i added another column rather its summed its showing '0' in the column. `With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count + 1).Offset(1, 0)
.Columns(.Columns.Count).Formula = "=sumifs(AA:AA, J:J, J2, L:L, L2, R:R, R2)"
.Columns(27) = .Columns(.Columns.Count).Value
.Columns(.Columns.Count).Formula = "=sumifs(AC:AC, J:J, J2, L:L, L2, R:R, R2)"                                                                                .Columns(29) = .Columns(.Columns.Count).Value
.Columns(.Columns.Count).Delete`
End With

Comment: @user3598756  please someone answer to my above comment and this comment .  if i excute the code for the first time its showing all the correct values again when i excuted the code for the second time its showing null values in the columns where the sum up values has to be summed in columns.

Answer (score 1):

here's "ballpark" #2

```
Sub main()
Dim helperRng As Range

With Worksheets("Sheet01")
    With .UsedRange
        Set helperRng = .Offset(, .Columns.Count + 1).Resize(, 1)
        With helperRng
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=concatenate(RC2, RC6, RC7)"
            .Offset(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=if(countif(R1C[-1]:RC[-1], RC[-1])=1,1,"""")"
            With .Offset(, 2)
                .FormulaR1C1 = "=sumif(C[-2], RC[-2],C5)"
                .Value = .Value
            End With
            .Offset(, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlTextValues).EntireRow.Delete
            Worksheets("Sheet01").Columns(5).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).Value = .Offset(1, 2).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Value
            helperRng.Resize(, 3).Clear
        End With
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

only curious which is faster!

Comment: Seems a bit slower than my single formula method; likely due to calculation but I like the approach.

Comment: @user3598756 Can you add a logic if the cells are empty make it skip.I have added your code into my huge code it showing an error 'no cells were found' because it creates a workbook and later have to work you with your code.

Comment: @Jeeper: so I lost...maybe more luck next time! buddha sreekanth: I didn't understand, post a small example file with which the code would throw an error

Answer (score 0):

This could be done in a 18 milliseconds (slight exaggeration) using arrays and dictionary object. I simplify the function by knowing my value to sum is in column 4. You can adjust code for multiple values in other columns. I'm writing from 1 array to another (InAy to OutAy), the dictionary determines if row already existed. The magic happens in the dictionary's Item property. I assign the item property value to the row (r) when a new OutAy row is written. Then when it exists already, I retrieve the row (r) where it was written to OutAy using the item property value: d.item(KeyIn) I can then update that value in OutAy(r, c) with a sum of existing value and new value 'KeyVal'.

This solves the same as sql query aggregate: "Select a, b, c, sum(d) from data group by a, b, c"

Note: add a tools->reference to Microsoft Scripting runtime

```
    sub some()
     ...
     data = Range("WhereYourDataIs") 'create data array
     Range("WhereYourDataIs").clear 'assumes you'll output to same location
     data = RemoveDupes(data) 'removedupes and sum values
     Range("A2").Resize(UBound(data), UBound(data, 2)) = data 'A2 assumes your data headers begin in row 1, column 1
     ...
    End Sub

Function RemoveDupes(InAy As Variant) As Variant
    Dim d As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set d = New Scripting.Dictionary
    ReDim OutAy(1 To UBound(InAy), 1 To 4)
    r = 1

    For i = 1 To UBound(InAy)
        KeyIn = ""
        KeyVal = InAy(i, 4) 'the value field to sum/aggregate if exists
        For c = 1 To 3 'a, b, c metadata to roll up
            KeyIn = KeyIn & InAy(i, c)
        Next c
        If d.Exists(KeyIn) Then
            OutAy(d.item(KeyIn), 4) = OutAy(d.item(KeyIn), 4) + KeyVal 'the summation of value field for existing row in OutAy
            Else:
            d.Add KeyIn, r 'r is set as the item value referencing the row of the OutAy when it was first added. The reference is used when .Exists is true
            For c = 1 To 4
                OutAy(r, c) = InAy(i, c)
            Next c
            r = r + 1
        End If
    Next
    RemoveDupes = OutAy
End Function
```